# finding registry key corresponding to group policy object

Tags: c#, registry

I have to edit Local group policy frequently. But it's path is too long to remember. So I want to control by program. They said gp object is the front end of the registry. But How can I find the registry key corresponding to the gp object.
Example path is

`administrative templates/windows components/remote desktop services/remote desktop session host/device and resource redirection/Do not allow clipboard redirection`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Registry.SetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.setvalue?view=netframework-4.8) function.

Example:

```
        const string userRoot = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER";
        const string subkey = "RegistrySetValueExample";
        const string keyName = userRoot + "\\" + subkey;

        // An int value can be stored without specifying the
        // registry data type, but long values will be stored
        // as strings unless you specify the type. Note that
        // the int is stored in the default name/value
        // pair.
        Registry.SetValue(keyName, "", 5280);
        Registry.SetValue(keyName, "TestLong", 12345678901234,
            RegistryValueKind.QWord);
```

> **keyName** String
>
> The full registry path of the key, beginning with a valid registry root, such as "HKEY_CURRENT_USER".

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I want to get group policy object. In your answer, want to get just `subkey`.  I get the answer from [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/115617/how-to-see-which-registry-settings-a-group-policy-object-modifies/). But the registry key path is disappeared or changed frequently. Could you help me?